# Strategy for blog integration with existing website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, blogs, disqus

I've made a website in ASP.Net MVC 5 and I want to look at creating a blog.  Purely to help drive traffic to my site.  But I don't want to start reinventing the wheel and writing my own blogging engine!  As far as I can see my options are (considering I'd want to host it locally):

Option 1)  Use a hosted blog engine, such as Wordpress (which is great).  This would involve installing PHP and MySQL on my webserver.  And I'd have to create a link that takes me 'away' from my MVC website and over to the PHP Wordpress website.  In other words it wouldn't integrate very well.

Option 2)  I could create a static 'blog template' page in MVC and manually create a blog entry myself as I would when I normally write a HTML page.  And every time I want to create a new blog entry I could copy and paste the page (and add a new URL route etc) and so on.  I could then use Disqus to paste a Disqus widget at the bottom of each blog page (i think that's how it works, right?).  If I needed to I could write a simple search page with blog title/link to blog page.  This way my blogs would integrate well with my website and I wouldn't be redirecting users to 'another site' (if that makes sense!)

I guess my concerns are:

1)  Would 'redirecting' to essentially a separate (local) website (such as hosted Wordpress) be a good user experience?  Even if I skinned it up to look similar to my own site?

2)  Is it 'messy'/unmanageable to manually create each blog page as above?  Just so that it integrates nicely with my MVC web application?

3)  And would it be best to go with a mature platform instead (such as Wordpress) which will probably have good plugins for SEO etc?

Just wondered what approach other people take in these situations, and what the best practice would be.

Thanks.

Comment: Just write articles on LinkedIn and share a link to your site at the bottom of the article. If people like your content they will follow you

Comment: Yeah, potentially an option.  Although that would drive traffic to LinkedIn, and then to my site.  But that's not a bad thing I don't suppose.  Interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: That's what a friend of mine does and his blog has benefited a decent amount from it actually, and it saved him a lot of the work you're talking about (unless you want to do that work)

Comment: Depends on what you're really after. You can certainly extend your existing site _yourself_ (and build a "CMS"), or you can use pre-existing ASP.Net CMS - same idea as WordPress above, but if your core is .Net, then you can bend it however you want. Depends on what you'd define as "comfortable" (maintain, modify, customize, etc).The plug-in world of Wordpress is great however. That's if comfortable to you means "plug and forget".